# Custom SOAP client DLL exposed as com component using vs2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

One of our clients have an existing access db which connects to our wsoap web service. MS has deprecated the library we once used to access the web service from VBA.

This custom DLL is my only choice other than writing a new app for them which am not authorized to do because of cost.

I've written the following class

```
namespace MAServicesComClient
{
    public class TiRequestComClient
    {
        public Task<ServiceReference1.SubmitAsXmlResponse> SubmitAsXmlRequest(string username, string password,string xml)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient srv = new ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient();
            return srv.SubmitAsXmlAsync(username, password, xml); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute that method in VBA it says it can't find a reference to the end point.

I have implemented this class within a console app and it works.

How do I get it to use the configuration file in the same directory as the access db file?

Edit:
It seems to work if I copy the dll file to where the database file is then register it using regasm.exe. Then drop the .dll.config where msaccess.exe is then rename to msaccess.exe.config.

But is there no way I can get to use the config within the same directory as the dll

Answer (score 0):

Quite sure you can FORCE load the config file with this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData ("APP_CONFIG_FILE",ConfigFile);
```

The configfile in above has to be a full path name. And if you place the .dll in the current folder. So something like this should work:

' intilize event:

```
    Dim strP As String

    strP = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location

    strP = strP & ".config"
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", strP)
```